# Make .toggleClass() to affect only one element with the same class on click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make dropdown menu with jQuery. Problem that my script effects all elements with the same class on click. Below is my problem in the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
    $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="parent">Home
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Johnny</li>
      <li>Julie</li>
      <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

I was trying to play around with :

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('.parent')
        .click(function () {
        $(this).children('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

but without any decent results. Could someone tell where I am missing the point? Many thanks for all possible help, looking forward.

Comment: your question related answer is given already with working code.. what else decent answer you want.
 even  the below code works properly (check my answer):
 $(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('.parent')
        .click(function () {
        $(this).children('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
  $('.parent').not(this).find('.sub-nav.visible').removeClass('visible');
    $('.sub-nav',this).toggleClass('visible');//find .sub-nav of clicked .parent
  });
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="parent">Home
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Johnny</li>
      <li>Julie</li>
      <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

1. Use `this` context
2. To get the clicked parent

Comment: Many thanks for great response. Is it possible to update script and make `toggleClass()` work only for one element, I mean, if I click on another `<li class="parent">` the previous one will automatically close.

Comment: Flawless @guradio , much obliged!

Comment: @o.O glad to help mate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="parent">Home
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Johnny</li>
      <li>Julie</li>
      <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use current object with this keyword:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="parent">Home
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Johnny</li>
      <li>Julie</li>
      <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```